# Scapy: Getting trailer field in the dissector

Tags: python, scapy

I'm using scapy to read and pretty print a trace file. The PDUs I'm reading (My_Packet) have the format:

```
| header | payload | crc |
--------------------------
```

The payload field contains another PDU inside. I'm using the following code to strip the crc part, but unfortunately something does not work as expected (I cannot figure out what's wrong).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *

class My_Packet(Packet):
    '''My_Packet PDU'''

    name = "My Packet"
    CRC_SIZE = 4

    fields_desc=[ LEShortField("len", 0) ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        """Build My_Packet"""
        self.crc = []
        super(My_Packet, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)

    def get_crc(self):
        """Get the CRC"""
        return self.crc

    def post_dissect(self, p):
        """Remove trailer/CRC"""
        self.crc = p[-self.CRC_SIZE:]
        return p[:self.len - self.CRC_SIZE]

    def extract_padding(self, p):
        """Remove trailer for the upper layer"""
        return p[:self.len - self.CRC_SIZE], p[self.len - self.CRC_SIZE:]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    bind_layers(UDP, My_Packet, sport=5001, dport=5001)

    packets = rdpcap("./tcpdump_5501.bin")

    # iterate through PDUs
    for pkt in packets:
        if pkt.haslayer(UDP):
            pld = pkt[My_Packet].load
            print("PDU: 0x{}".format(pld.encode("hex")))

            crc = pkt[My_Packet].get_crc()
            print("CRC: 0x{}".format(crc.encode("hex")))
```

The runtime error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./so.py", line 41, in <module>
    pld = pkt[My_Packet].load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 964, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError("Layer [%s] not found" % lname)
IndexError: Layer [My_Packet] not found
```

Scapy version: Version git-archive.dev9fc949739
Python version: Python 2.7.12

Comment: Do all the packets from the pcap file contain a "My_Packet" layer or just some of them?

Comment: Just some of them.  
1. When I remove from the My_Packet class all the references to self.crc, everything is fine.  
2. replacing "if pkt.haslayer(UDP):" with "if pkt.haslayer(UDP) and pkt.haslayer(My_Packet):" does not print anything.  
3. Is there support in scapy to define trailers in the same way as for header fields?

Comment: To check if My_Packet layer is present try with `if My_Packet in packet` - this works for the default protocols so maybe since packet is actually raw bytes should work also with your protocol.

Comment: Another way would be to use a `try:...except IndexError:` to handle the exception (packets that do not contain your layer cause the exception). Such that the packets that do not contain your layer will be handled by the exception - I think you could try that too!

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Scapy 2.5.0, there's a new special field that you can use for that: [FCSField](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.fields.html#scapy.fields.FCSField)

For instance:

```
from scapy.packet import Packet
from scapy.fields import LEShortField, FCSField

class My_Packet(Packet):
    fields_desc = [
        LEShortField("len", None),
        FCSField("crc", 0, fmt="<I")
    ]
```

`FCSField` is just an alias of the [`TrailerField`](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.fields.html#scapy.fields.TrailerField) that wraps a `Field`, so you could also do: (useful if you use a more complex, non-integer field)

```
from scapy.packet import Packet
from scapy.fields import LEShortField, LEIntField, TrailerField

class My_Packet(Packet):
    fields_desc = [
        LEShortField("len", None),
        TrailerField(LEIntField("crc", 0))
    ]
```